# How can I contribute when many duplicate questions are all missing an important element in the answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Today I was looking for how to find the *parent* (container) user control in [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

As you can see from my browser history, I found a lot of duplicate questions which are proposing the same solution* (use this.Parent or VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) or LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this)

[image]

They all (except one) forgot to mention that "you need to place the code in the Initialized event handler" [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205310/196210).

What is the best practice in this case? How can we avoid other people to get mad as I did?

*I forgot to say that I tried two approaches. Part of the questions relates to the other approach which was based on the parent UI element passing itself as a parameter to the child element.

Comment: Vote to close the duplicate questions as duplicates of the one with the correct answer?

Comment: @Nick: thanks, it's funny that the solution was quite easy

Comment: If only one answer includes this information, but they all have been upvoted / accepted, perhaps it's not such a big deal?  I would be inclined to upvote, and perhaps leave a comment highlighting the usefulness of that nugget of information.

Comment: [1/2] "Correct" depends on your use-case. In this specific instance, I'd say that it is somehow obvious that you can only query the parent after the child element has been attach to the parent. A computer can not guess to which parent a control might be attached at some point. The problem here seems to occure due to missing knowledge about when controls are attached to the visual/logical tree in WPF. But if you would listen all such pre-requisites and special cases would make the answers terribly long.

Comment: [2/2] If you really want to document the fact that none of the methods works before attaching the control to the visual tree, ask a new question along the line of "How to query the parent control before attaching a control to the visual tree", although I would expect mostly answers stating that this is not possible unless you pass the information yourself.

Comment: @BDL: yes, it's an ignorance of mine about how Xaml works. I didn't wonder on what was happening behind the scenes of the .NET framework. I thought that the framework would instantiate the user control, populating "somehow" all it's properties (just to let you understand what I mean, if you try to access the StackTrace you always find it already populated. I have never wondered on how it's populated.

Comment: @BDL: the point is that you already know that executiong those method before the OnLoaded means "before attaching the control to the visual tree". 70% of devs aren't even an account on SO... at least in my country :sweatgrin:

Comment: To be fair, it's likely that people have this same problem for a variety of reasons. Just because your case happened to be solved by my answer doesn't mean that that is the only possible solution in every case. Although, wow... looking at your screenshot, there are clearly a lot of duplicate questions, so something should be done about those. A variety of answers on the same question is helpful for researchers (you should read all the answers on a page); a zillion different *questions*? Not so much.